# Android new Intent with back button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, back-button

In my Android App I use an empty activity with one button. If I push the button I call a new activity with an intent. But on the new activity the back button (top left) to jump back to the last page is missing. Isn't there already a activity template from android studio or a spezial intent call to do this? Or what is the best way to do this?

This is the function which is called on the button press

```
void scanClicked(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The ServiceActivity is just an Empty Activity

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NavigationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".ServiceActivity"
        android:label="@string/annualServiceTitle">
    </activity>
```

Comment: show your code .

Comment: sorry I edited the code

Comment: you can use *supportFinishAfterTransition()* or simply call *finish()* on click event of the newly added activity

Comment: And also make sure you are not calling *finish()* or adding attribute *noHistory* prior to calling the new activity.

Comment: Added the manifest.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 options to do that.

Either you can use the android ToolBar in your XML 
[Adding toolbar](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

Or you can add a Layout which has a ImageButton aligned to the left of the layout. Then you can do this.

```
ImageButton backBtn;

backBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

In the second activity ..make your activity extend AppCompactActivity

and in onCreate add

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and override the onOptionsItemSelected in activity as

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with two lines of code:

In OnCreate of the second View:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and in the Manifest add attribute "parentActivityName" to the second View:

```
android:parentActivityName="fronius.com.serviceapp_frontend.NavigationActivity"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is based on your app theme defining in `styles.xml` file. 
If you are using `DarkActionBar` theme as you said, you **just** need to add `android:parentActivityName="fronius.com.serviceapp_frontend.NavigationActivity"`
 in your manifest file. 
But if you are using `NoActionBar` theme to use toolbar in your activities (as mentioned in Material Design) you have to add this line of code to visible up navigation button in your activity in addition to specify `parentActivityName`: 
`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` 
 Also you can change the up navigation button icon by this line of code:
               `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_back);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` in your `ServiceActivity.java` like this:

```
public class ServiceActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // etc...
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

On the activity you want to move to *ServiceActivity* call intent by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And on the *ServiceActivity* handle the click event and call

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        supportFinishAfterTransition();
        // or call
        finish();
    }
});
```